# How would I write an interpreter for this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scripting

I want to write an interpreter for a scripting language in javascript. Something that could run this script:

```
set myVariable to "Hello World"
repeat 5 times with x
begin
    set myVariable to myVariable plus " " plus x
end
popup "myVariable is: " plus myVariable
```

The equivalent javascript of the above would be:

```
var myVariable = "Hello World";
for (var x=1; x<=5; x++) {
    myVariable += " " + x;
}
alert("myVariable is: " + myVariable);
```

I don't want to translate from one to the other, I want to write a javascript program to interprete and execute the script directly. How can this be done?

Update:

I'm looking for a tutorial (preferably in javascript but C would do) that will walk me through this. I guess I'm looking for one that does not use any external tools as the tools seem to be my issue. I don't want to use something that calls libraries and a bunch of pre-built code. I want to see the whole thing, done from scratch.

Comment: you need to narrow the scope of your question.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky - The title is the question. I'll add it to the body of the post as well though

Comment: And what have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?  Perhaps pick up a book on compilers.

Comment: @Kevin - I've looked online at things like flex and ANTLRWorks. I've also not found a nice simple tutorial to walk me through creating something like this. I would also like to do this in javascript, not c/c++ (all the tutorial's I have seen).

Comment: `I want to see the whole thing, done from scratch.`, I hope you have time to spare... and good coffee.

Comment: This is kind of later but here is a GREAT article in writing an interpreter in JavaScript. It might get you some ideas and howto's: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345888/How-to-write-a-simple-interpreter-in-JavaScript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I'll actually try to tackle this question somewhat... although there is no way I could possibly distill everything you need to know into a few sentences or even paragraphs.

First, you should gain an understanding / familiarity with what's involved in building a compiler. You say you want to "interpret" the code - but, I think what you really want is to compile the code to Javascript (and in Javascript as well).

Wikipedia has a great page on the topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

The gist of the thing is:

1.) Convert the text (source code) into some sort of in-memory data structure ([abstract syntax tree - AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)) that actually lets you reason about the structure of the program you've been given.

2.) Given that structure, produce your output (Javascript, in this case).

To break down step 1 a bit further - Define your [*grammar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) e.g.; what is valid syntax in this new language of yours, and what is not? Typically, it's best to reason about this sort of thing with [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) on paper (or whatever syntax the tools you use prefer - although (E)BNF is the standard). The challenging part about this step is not only doing the grunt work of parsing the source code - but also making sure you've come up with a grammar that is *unambiguous* and *readily parsable*. Those two requirements are actually somewhat more difficult to nail down than you might think.

I've built an LALR parser generator in C# - and, I can tell you, unless you've built one before, it's not a trivial task. Beyond that, there are so many good ones, that, unless you are really wanting to know how it works for the fun of it or because you're into that kind of thing, it makes a whole lot more sense to use a parser-generator someone else wrote. The great thing about a parser generator is that it will take that syntax definition you've come up with convert it into a program that will spit out an AST the other end. That's a HUGE amount of work that was just done for you. And, in fact, there are a few for Javascript:

http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+parser+generator

[PEG.js – Parser Generator for JavaScript](http://pegjs.majda.cz/)

[JS/CC Parser Generator Project Homepage](http://jscc.jmksf.com/)

On to step 2. This step can be very basic for something like infix expressions - or it can get very complex. But, the idea is, given the AST, "convert" it into your output format (Javascript). Typically you need to check for things that aren't checked for by the "simple" syntax checking that occurs in the parser. For example, even in your sample code there is a whole number of things that could possibly go wrong. In the part where you say `plus x` what would happen if the developer never defined `x`? Should this be an error? Should `x` default to some value? This is where your language really comes to life. And, to back-track for a minute - your time needs to be spent on this step - not on the parser. Use a tool for that - seriously. You're talking about starting a large and challenging project - don't make it even harder for yourself. To add to all this - there is often a need to make multiple "passes" through the AST. For example, the first pass may look for and setup "module" definitions, the second pass may look for and setup "namespaces", another pass may setup classes, etc. These further refinements of the structure of the final application are used in later steps to determine if a reference to a particular class/variable/module/etc is valid (it actually exists or can be referenced).

There are a few really great books on compilers. The infamous ["dragon book"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) is one.

Comment: Well +1 since I forgot to mention the dragon book.

Comment: @talnicolas - LOL.. the one required reference for any compiler intro question : )

Answer (score 2):

What you are apparently trying to achieve is writing a new language. If I'm right then you gonna have to go through the following processus:

- Define a grammar that will recognize your language.
- Give this grammar to a tool like JS/CC ([here](http://jscc.jmksf.com/), generating Javascript), SableCC ([here](http://sablecc.org/), generating Java) or antlr ([here](http://www.antlr.org/), generating lots of languages), that will produce for you a parser.
- Then you will be able to implement the interpreter (or even a compiler if ever you need one) for your language based on what the parser generator will have given you.

I only used SableCC, which is a very powerful tool, and there are a lot of simple grammar examples in the archive proposed on the site that will possibly guide you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the answer I see everywhere I look. If there are examples they all produce c/c++ code that calls a ton of build-in library functions. I'm looking for a *simple* tutorial that walks me through this. I would guess I'm looking for a tutorial that walks me through this without using any tools.

Comment: I guess that if it is the answer you see everywhere, it is definitely the way to go. I know that doesn't sound easy, but no one said writing a new language was easy.

Comment: From this list(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators), there are 4 or 5 that generate Javascript apparently. If you try to write your own parser in Javascript, it will be way more difficult for you than learning one of these tools believe me.

Comment: +1 for responding to this question even when it had a -1 vote tally.

Comment: @Steve thanks, I actually kinda like this domain and happy that my university gave a great course on it. So I don't miss a chance when it comes to parser, compilers and co :)

Comment: @talnicolas - Yeah, me too - but unforntunately the programming language development shop down the street isn't hiring ;)

Comment: @Steve ahah that's true, but who knows maybe one day you'll be able to create the new great language that everyone wants thanks to this knowledge ;)

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers you're getting are focusing on the parsing part of making an evaluator.  See [Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/) for an treatment on writing a semantics for a language.

Comment: We once had a mug with a poem on it which went something like this; "First you crawl and then you walk - Pretty soon you learn to talk." It went on to say something about stooping and getting old being like pidgin poop - but, you get the idea. I think we're all waiting to see if he will even get past the first logical step before we worry about the second.

Comment: @Steve - I'm trying... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352646/looking-for-a-little-help-and-guidance-on-creating-a-grammar-for-js-cc